# Qual è il significato di "secca" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nella versione in italiano dell'episodio *La nascita del villano* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> Ponigli una gabella [tassa] **secca** sulla paga 
>   mettigli una gabella persino su quel che caga.
>    
>   Di carnevale lascialo pur ballare 
>   e pur cantare che s'abbia da allegrare 
>                  [cosí che si possa rallegrare] 
>   ma poco, che non si debba scordare
>    
>   che è a 'sto mondo per faticare.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "secco" in alcuni dizionari ma, tra le tantissime accezioni che appaiono, non so a quale corrisponda l'uso che se ne fa nel passaggio precedente. Qualcuno di voi me lo saprebbe spiegare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'aggettivo ***secca*** in questo caso indica una trattenuta prefissata, inevitabile e automatica sulla paga del villano.

Infatti in Italia esiste anche la [cedolare secca](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/cedolare-secca_%28Dizionario-di-Economia-e-Finanza%29/) che corrisponde a

> Imposta sostitutiva del tributo personale progressivo sul reddito, che
>   tassa in maniera prefissata, a prescindere dalle altre entrate, alcuni
>   tipi di reddito. Può essere classificata come imposta autonoma diretta
>   sul reddito, proporzionale e riscossa mediante ritenuta alla fonte a
>   titolo definitivo. Il soggetto che subisce tale ritenuta estingue il
>   suo debito con il fisco.

In questo caso l'aggettivo secca indica l'immediatezza della tassa e il suo effetto puntuale, automatico ed estintivo con il fisco.

Esiste, sempre nell'ambito economico, anche l'espressione [perdita secca](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/perdita/)

> p. secca, perdita di denaro senza alcuna compensazione;

e anche qui il significato di secca indica l'immediatezza e l'ineludibilità della perdita.